# How is full reflection (mirror) compatible with the fresnel equations

Tags: reflection, refraction

I'm working on a raytracer with realistic material properties and I am using the Fresnel Equations to calculate the chance of a ray being reflected or refracted on a material boundry. It seems though that the reflectivity does not behave as expected. I have created a sphere with the index of refraction of mercury and it pretty much has the same reflective properties as a parafin or plastic object. I would have expected near-full reflectivity here. Is there more to reflection than the fresnel equations ?

Comment: The Fresnel equations tell you how much light passes through and how much is reflected. But it does not tell you have specular/diffuse the surface is.

Answer (score 1):

For metals, the index of refraction is a complex number.  The Fresnel equations remain valid when the index is complex:  $n_\mathrm{complex}=n + ik$.

Using only the real part only is not adequate.   Both values for Mercury, and many other materials can be found [on this very useful website](http://refractiveindex.info/?shelf=main&book=Hg&page=Inagaki).  Lower down on that page you will see the results for transmission and reflection of Mercury, and you will see that they do not resemble paraffin.

Comment: Uh, I didn't know that. Is it possible to adapt Schlick's approximation for complex numbers ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you there.  You might ask at a forum more closely related to computer graphics.

Comment: Okay I might. One last question: Could I use the regular Fresnel Equations and just use complex numbers instead of the ior ?

Comment: Yes, you can ... but what is "ior"?  Is that a typo?

Comment: Index of refraction

Comment: The answer is still yes.  The Fresnel equations are valid for complex index.  Be careful to do the complex algebra correctly.  Maybe your software supports complex numbers.

Comment: Unfortunately wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations only explains the equations in a magnetic medium using wave impendances, not the refractive index and extinction coefficient. Do you have a source for a better explanation ?

Comment: I did a quick search on "complex fresnel equations" and found [this](https://www.ifm.liu.se/courses/TFYY67/Lect13.pdf).  It might deal only with normal incidence though.  Not sure, I did not read the whole thing.